# Instrumentation Amplifier - is it possible to have an output signal inverted, with respect to the supply voltage?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell

I'm doing some circuit design in order to translate a load cell input into the pedal input of a Logitech G27. What I want to achieve involves having a balanced state output as close to 5V from the amplifier as possible (the original pedal outputs 4.9V, using a potentiometer as a voltage divider to measure the travel), and at full load on the load cell have a lower voltage (original reads 1.4V at full load).

[image: Load cell amplifier circuit]

Circuit simulation: [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%204.078577355933338%2054%205%2043%0Ag%20240%20256%20240%20272%200%0AR%20240%2096%20240%2048%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20176%20128%20240%20128%200%0Aw%20240%20128%20304%20128%200%0Aw%20176%20256%20240%20256%200%0Aw%20240%20256%20304%20256%200%0Ap%20224%20304%20256%20304%201%200%0Aw%20128%20192%20128%20304%200%0Aw%20352%20192%20352%20304%200%0Aw%20256%20304%20352%20304%200%0Aw%20224%20304%20128%20304%200%0Ap%20240%20448%20336%20448%201%200%0Ar%20352%20304%20448%20304%200%2010000%0Ar%20128%20304%2032%20304%200%2010000%0Ag%2032%20304%2032%20336%200%0Ag%20448%20304%20448%20336%200%0Ac%20240%2096%20400%2096%200%200.00001%205%0Ag%20400%2096%20400%20128%200%0Aw%20240%2096%20240%20128%200%0Ar%20176%20128%20176%20192%200%20998%0Aw%20128%20192%20176%20192%200%0Aw%20352%20192%20304%20192%200%0Ar%20176%20192%20176%20256%200%201002%0Ar%20304%20128%20304%20192%200%201000%0Ar%20304%20192%20304%20256%200%201000%0Aa%20240%20304%20240%20448%208%205%200%201000000%202.3809523809523805%202.385714740136141%201005%0A38%2019%200%20998%201002%20R1%0A38%2022%200%20998%201002%20R2%0A). Sorry, I haven't translated it to CircuitLab, hopefully this will suffice. Based on a design from [here](http://cbtechnical.blogspot.com/2011/04/amplifier-circuit.html), albeit the design there is using an INA122 (similar to the INA126, but with different internal resistances which alter the gain calculation).

What I currently have is a straight amplifier circuit, using an INA126 IC. The load cell is a half-bridge model, with 1000 ohm resistance at no load on both sides. At max compression, the resistance changes to roughly 1002/998 ohm on respective arms. This resistance difference is converted using a Wheatstone bridge by the INA126 (represented in the simulation as a single op-amp, since the simulation only has singular op-amps; the INA126 is a two op-amp instrumentation amplifier with an external gain resistor, setting the gain to roughly 1000; and having internal feedback connections [[datasheet]](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina126.pdf)).

In terms of voltages available, I only have one 5V source, and no negative voltage supplies available.

Is it possible to reconfigure this circuit to output on a 5v-0v scale, rather than 0v-5v, without adding any more op-amps or ICs? Or will another rail-to-rail op-amp be required, purely to invert the voltage on this scale?

Comment: Your op-amp has no feedback.  How is it that it is not acting as a comparator?

Comment: When you have a differential amplifier, you can invert the signal by simply swapping the inputs.

Comment: @TimWescott: I think we can assume that the amplifier shown is the INA, with an implicit gain-setting resistor.

Comment: @DaveTweed: in the simulation he links to, the device is called out as an op-amp, not an instrumentation amp.  If it *were* an instrumentation amp, and it were rail-rail, then a first-cut solution would be to connect the reference to 5V -- I'm not sure if normal instrumentation amplifiers are that versatile, though.

Comment: I've added a little more detail in the question.
@TimWescott: the op-amp in the simulation is used as a representation of the full INA126 chip, which is a two op-amp instrument amplifier. It's not quite rail-to-rail, though.

Comment: @DaveTweed: The op-amp is in there as a substitute for the full INA126 chip, with a gain resistor setting it to a gain of roughly 1000; this is set in the simulation as a property of the op-amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this.

- Swap the input pins.
- Connect the `REF` pin to +5 V.

(caveat: I haven't tried such high voltages on the REF pin myself, and I'm not specifically familiar with the INA126)

In order to be sure of getting 5 V output with the INA126, you need a positive supply voltage of at least 5.9 V, and to be sure of getting a 0 V output you need a negative supply voltage below -0.95 V. If your load currents are very low, you may get away with smaller margins between the output voltages and the supply voltages.

Comment: This looks like a good line to follow. As stated in the post, the voltages I'm trying to reach range from 1.4V to 4.9V, so the 0V requiring a negative supply voltage is a non-issue. However, the top end of the voltage range looks like an issue, since I can't add any other voltage sources which would be higher voltage.

Comment: @redion1992 if the load pulls up to 5 V rather than down to 0 V, you might get outputs closer to 5 V. But you'll have to experiment with the INA126 to find out how close.

Comment: Well, I managed to get the top end of the voltage (at no load) to reach 3.3V, and that worked fine with the G27 as a nil reading. Thanks for your help on this!